# Are there any linting rules for vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Is there any linting rules available for vuejs?  I am using single page components with ES6 syntax. I am currently using rallycoding however I think this does not suit vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are the same, as a normal Javascript Project.

You can take a look into this [.eslintrc.js](https://github.com/Ethaan/vuexpresso/blob/master/.eslintrc.js) file.

Its up to you how you load them, and also you need to install the correct plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Vue now has an [official style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/) with "essentials" and "recommended" conventions. There are [eslint configs based on the style guide](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue) that you can add to your project, and if you create a new project with the Vue CLI tool it will ask if you want to pre-configure it with eslint out of the box.

```js
    // example from my .eslintrc.js file
    extends: [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        '@vue/airbnb',
    ],
```

Then you could change `vue/essential` to `vue/recommended` for more comprehensive rules.